# TDS and TFS integration

Tags: tfs, tds

am getting below issue while connecting the TDS with VS 2015.

> Creating directory
>   "\10.207.7.199\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\DEVCMS\Website_DEV". C:\Program
>   Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\HedgehogDevelopment.SitecoreProject.targets(560,5):
>   Error MSB3021: Unable to copy file "C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\MSBuild\HedgehogDevelopment\SitecoreProject\v9.0\TdsService.asmx"
>   to
>   "\10.207.7.199\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\DEVCMS\Website_DEV\TdsService.asmx".
>   Access to the path
>   '\10.207.7.199\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\DEVCMS\Website_DEV' is denied.

Also am able to access the `\\10.207.7.199\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\DEVCMS\Website\_DEV` path from build server.

Comment: Which vserion of TDS are you using? Did you install the TDS on the build server. As of **TDS 5.5** you don't need to install on the build server and can use cloud build by installing a nuget package: http://hedgehogdevelopment.github.io/tds/chapter5.html#tds-builds-using-cloud-servers

Answer (score 0):

This looks like you are attempting to deploy with TDS to a target website and you do not have permission to do so. Try running Visual Studio in 'administrator mode' to see if this resolves the permission issue.

Also, validate that the path you are attempting to deploy to is correct. It does not look valid, as I would have expected it to have a double slash at the beginning for a network path and then a slash at the end before _DEV.

Also, you appear to be accessing the C$ drive on a networked server. Typically you must be the administrator on that system in order for this to function correctly. I would recommend instead setting up a UNC Share folder that you will allow to write to a particular folder (maybe the Website folder) for any requests from your deployment system.